# How to use @Media Query in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, media-queries

I am using High-chart Graphs, how to make tool-tip or legend font size responsive. How to use @media-query for tool-tip. This is my code

```
var plotOptions = {
 pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      depth: 35,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b style="font-size:20px;">{point.name}:: {point.y:.1f}</b>',
        style: {
                   color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
             }
          }
       };

var  legend={
    enabled: true,
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    width: 200,
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    useHTML: true,
    labelFormatter: function() {
    return '<table style="border:0"><tr><td style="font-size:24px;"> ' + this.name + ' - </td> <td style="font-size:24px;"> ' +             this.y + ' </td></tr></table> <br />';
};
```

Comment: Use responsive option (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3et0ojye/.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Highcharts API `responsive`option. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules
There you can defines multiple rules and override any other defined charts options. This is what you ask for. Define for example `label.styles` and override them by a rule.
Here an example of a rule definition:

```
responsive: {
  rules: [{
    condition: {
      maxWidth: 500
    },
    chartOptions: {
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

### Update

You need at least Highcharts 5.0 to use the responsive option.

Also back to your question using media queries. Highcharts generate a svg and set inline styles without using class names. Also it refresh/repaint the charts when window resize. So setting stylings with css is very hard, if not impossible.